# VHDL type of variable is incompatible with type of function call

Tags: function, variables, vhdl

I am trying to use a function in vhdl to return an array of 4 integers.There is not syntax errors within my code besides the following: Type of holder is incompatible with type of encryption.

```
  type matrix1x4 is array (0 to 3) of integer;
begin
  input <= digit1 & digit2;
process(digit1,digit2)
    begin
        encryptFlag <= '0';
        decryptFlag <= '0';
        input <= digit1 & digit2;
        O <= input;
end process;

process(encry)

    variable holder: matrix1x4;
    begin
        if encryptFlag = '0' and encry = '1' then
            encryptFlag <= '1'; 
            decryptFlag <= '1';
            holder := encryption(input);
```

Code within my package that holds my function encryption:

```
    type matrix1x2 is array (0 to 1) of integer;
type matrix1x4 is array (0 to 3) of integer;
type matrix2x2 is array (1 to 2, 1 to 2) of integer;
function encryption (input: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)) return 
             matrix1x4;
```

Code within my encryption function:

```
    variable s1, s2: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
variable char1, char2: character;
variable int1, int2,temp1,temp2: integer;
variable inputMat: matrix1x2;
variable encodeMat: matrix2x2;
variable O: matrix1x4;
begin
    s1 := input(7 downto 4);
    char1 := binToChar(s1);
    int1 := charToInt(char1);
    s2 := input(3 downto 0);
    char2 := binToChar(s2);
    int2 := charToInt(char2);
    inputMat:= (int1,int2);
    encodeMat:= ((1,1),(3,4));
    temp1 := inputMat(0) * encodeMat(1,1) + inputMat(1) * encodeMat(1,2);
    temp2 := inputMat(1) * encodeMat(2,1) + inputMat(0) * encodeMat(2,2);
    int1    := temp1;
    int2    := temp2;
    temp1 := (temp1 mod 16) + 1;
    temp2 := (temp2 mod 16) + 1;
    O :=  (int1,int2, temp1, temp2);
return O;
```

Comment: Because both types are not identical. Types are not equal based on structure, but on names. you declared two similar structured byes in different places, thus, they are not the same and not compatible.

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 6.2 Type declarations "NOTE 1—Two type definitions always define two distinct types, even if they are lexically identical. ..."

Comment: @Paebbels thank you for the help, this error does make sense. Could you check out my full code here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55694750/error-this-signal-is-connected-to-multiple-drivers I have more errors that I think you could help me fix.

Comment: @user1155120  thank you for the help both you and Paebbles has help me understand the error. Could you check out my full code here: stackoverflow.com/questions/5569475.. I am getting more errors then expected